# Listar todos os dados com o mesmo id

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou com o seguinte problema: tenho uma tabela chamada `pedido`. Nessa tabela eu pego dados de outras duas tabelas:

[image: tabela pedido]

Eu gostaria de fazer uma lista somente dos produtos que tenham o mesmo `id_venda`. No meu código só aparece o primeiro item adicionado com id igual:

```
    <?php

$perfil1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pedido WHERE id_venda='$id'");

$lista=list($id, $produtosb , $idvenda)=mysql_fetch_row($perfil1);


$prod = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto=". $lista[1];
$query = mysql_query($prod);
$b=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$prod = $b ['produtos'];

?>

<input type="text" name="id" style="width: 450px" readonly="true"  value="<?php echo $prod; ?>"><br>
```

Eu tentei usar o Loop while, mas ele retorna todos os dados da tabela. Qual laço de repetição eu deveria usar?

Comment: `select * from pedidos inner join produtos on produtos = id_produto where id_venda= $id` Basta pegar o resultado e listar usando while.

Comment: Se eu fosse você usaria PDO bem mais pratico e seguro para trabalhar com banco de dados. Essa função do mysql_* ficou obsoleta, a partir do php 7 ela não vai mais existir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos lá...

Partindo do principio que a coluna `produtos` seja o ID do produto da venda na tabela  `pedidos`, e com `id_venda` definido, resolvemos o problema com uma query apenas:

Supondo que sua coluna `produtos` tenha:

```
id | nome
```

Eis o select:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto in (SELECT produtos FROM pedido WHERE id_venda='$id')";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

print $db_field['ID'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['nome'] . "<BR>";

}
```

EDIT:

Utilização com join:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM pedido inner join produtos on produtos = id_produto where id_venda='$id'";
```

Comment: inner join não seria melhor do que subquerys?

Comment: Opa amigo vlw pela ajuda fiz algumas mudanças e deu certinho pra min , muito obg ;)

Comment: Rapaz....há uma discussão severa pelo mundo a respeito disso.... rs. Eu sempre usei inner join... de um tempo pra ca, comecei usar join no where... e as vezes subqueries.. Acho que no fim das contas, prevalece o que for melhor visualmente ... Como é somente minha opinião, coloquei um exemplo utilizando o `inner join` ;)

Comment: Sem problemas Marllon :-)  Só tem um errinho na query de join, está "joinando" produtos com ela mesma, acho que seria com a tabela `Pedido`.

Comment: verdade! haha editei lá! valeu, @DiegoFelipe

Comment: Isso tá com cara de ser assunto pra [outer join, e não inner](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join?s=2|1.5342).